# ASP.NET MVC: versioning static scripts (outside of bundles)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

In my ASP.NET app, I have several pages/scripts that I can't bundle - PDF.js viewer page or MediaElement video loader.

But sometimes I do minor amendments to those scripts; I need to version/cache-bust the respective script files, so these are auto-reloaded for users. In PDF.js viewer.html, for example:

```
<script src="viewer.js?v=1.1"></script>
```

The gotcha is: how to make ASP.NET/IIS auto-inject the version info into the static HTML files that it serves? Any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any type of task runner?

I use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), and whenever I build, I have a task to replace my version number with something unique to ensure the latest version is always requested.

So in my `Index.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/bundle.js?v=$$VERSION" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('version', function () {
    return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(replace('$$VERSION', Date.now()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Nope, I don't use gulp; I wonder if the same can be done with post-build scripts of Visual Studio?

Comment: No problem! Hopefully a similar solution can be done.